# Is there any way for make to generate an output file from components compiled on different branches?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

We assemble release images from two source binaries: binary1.bin and binary2.bin. I'd like to have make automatically compile "binary1.bin" from sources on branch1 and compile "binary2.bin" from sources on branch2

I’m developing a project for an embedded platform. We’re currently using ARM’s C/C++ Compiler and GNU make for our build system. We have a single repo for all code.

During a normal build, Binary1.bin and Binary2.bin are built from separate files (with some files in common) in the same branch (say branch1), and then combined into Release_image.img, ready for loading onto device.

The problem is that sometimes we’d like to combine “Binary1.bin” generated from branch1, while “Binary2.bin” would be generated from branch2. This happens, for instance, if we'd like to temporarily freeze "Binary2.bin" in time while investigating bugs or validating new changes.

Is there any way to get make to handle this automatically? Right now, we have to switch branches and manually assemble Release_image.img ourselves from the component binaries, which is both slow and error-prone.

We are open to restructuring the repository if need be, or to alternative build tools.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but could you have a make rule for Release_image.img that checks out branch1, does a $(MAKE) Binary1.bin (possibly preceded by a $(MAKE) clean-Binary1), checks out branch2, does a $(MAKE) Binary2.bin, and then combines the resulting files into Release_image.img?

Comment: Your branches should be set up so all the code you need to build a release are in one branch. Make a branch3 that has the stuff from branch1 and branch2 that you need. The branches shouldn’t be too different than each other otherwise they’re more like complete forks of the code. These are supposed to get merged together again at some point right?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Normally binary1.bin and binary2.bin are both generated from branch1, but every once in a while we need to use binary1.bin from branch1 and binary2.bin from branch2.

This occurs, for example, if we need to temporarily "freeze" binary2.bin at a certain point in history due to bugs or validation issues.

Comment: Ok, what if it checks out branch1, does $(MAKE) Binary1.bin, copies Binary2.bin to a temporary directory, checks out branch2, does $(MAKE) Binary2.bin, copies Binary1.bin from the temporary directory to overwrite branch2's Binary1.bin, then combines the files into Release_image.img?

Comment: Why not have two checkouts? I.e. the main one on branch1, which you normally use, and the 2nd one on branch2, which you only update on those "historic moments" when you freeze branch2. Then update your makefile to accept a pre-built binary2.bin from another location.

Answer (score 0):

As you have two different source trees (branch1 & branch2) you won't be able to solve this using one build directory (well, at least not without hacking around and overwriting stuff). I.e. this problem has nothing to do with make.

I would suggest to use two checkouts, the 2nd one on branch2 that only gets updated when you "freeze" branch2 for bug and validation work. Then your makefile would be something like the following

```make
ifndef BINARY2
BINARY2 := binary2.bin
endif

.PHONY: all
all: Release_image.img

Release_image.img: binary1.bin $(BINARY2)
      ....

binary1.bin: ....
      ....

binary2.bin: ....
      ....
```

On the main checkout you can now use

```bash
# normal development build
$ make

# bug hunting/validation build using another binary2.bin
$ make BINARY2=<... path to 2nd checkout...>/binary2.bin
```

On the second checkout you would use

```bash
# build binary2.bin @ <commit>
$ git checkout -b topic-bug-hunting <commit>
$ git clean -xfd
$ make binary2.bin
```